# Rspec Load Error in Ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rspec

I am working through Hartl's Ruby on Rails tutorial and am trying to test for user signups with invalid information and am getting a "Load Error" when running rspec. I am unsure how to fix this error, as I have updated my gem files.

```
$ bundle exec rspec spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb \ > -e "signup with invalid information"
```

then I get this message:

```
/Users/kelvinyu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `load': cannot load such file -- /Users/kelvinyu/rails_projects/sample_app/signup with invalid information (LoadError)
from /Users/kelvinyu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `block in load_spec_files'
from /Users/kelvinyu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `each'
from /Users/kelvinyu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:819:in `load_spec_files'
from /Users/kelvinyu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/command_line.rb:22:in `run'
from /Users/kelvinyu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:77:in `rescue in run'
from /Users/kelvinyu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:73:in `run'
from /Users/kelvinyu/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p247@railstutorial_rails_4_0/gems/rspec-core-2.13.1/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:17:in `block in autorun'
```

Here is my spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb:

```
require 'spec_helper'

describe "UserPages" do

  subject { page }

  describe "profile page" do
    let(:user) { FactoryGirl.create(:user) }
    before { visit user_path(user) }

    it { should have_content(user.name) }
    it { should have_title(user.name) }
  end

  describe "signup page" do
    before { visit signup_path }
      # Run the generator again with the --webrat flag if you want to use webrat methods/matchers
    it { should have_content('Sign up') }
    it { should have_title(full_title('Sign up')) }
  end

  describe "signup" do

    before { visit signup_path }

    let(:submit) { "Create my account" }

    describe "with invalid information" do
      it "should not create a user" do
        expect { click_button submit }.not_to change(User, :count)
      end
    end

    describe "with valid information" do
      before do
        fill_in "Name",         with: "Example User"
        fill_in "Email",        with: "user@example.com"
        fill_in "Password",     with: "foobar"
        fill_in "Confirmation", with: "foobar"
      end

      it "should create a user" do
        expect { click_button submit }.to change(User, :count).by(1)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

And my Gemfile:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'
ruby '2.0.0'
#ruby-gemset=railstutorial_rails_4_0

gem 'rails', '4.0.0'
gem 'bootstrap-sass', '2.3.2.0'
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '3.0.1'
gem 'faker', '1.1.2'
gem 'will_paginate', '3.0.4'
gem 'bootstrap-will_paginate', '0.0.9'

group :development, :test do
  gem 'sqlite3', '1.3.7'
  gem 'rspec-rails', '2.13.1'
  # The following optional lines are part of the advanced setup.
  gem 'guard-rspec', '2.5.0'
  gem 'spork-rails', github: 'sporkrb/spork-rails'
  gem 'guard-spork', '1.5.0'
  gem 'childprocess', '0.3.6'
end

group :test do
  gem 'selenium-webdriver', '2.0.0'
  gem 'capybara', '2.1.0'
  gem 'factory_girl_rails', '4.2.1'
  gem 'cucumber-rails', '1.3.0', :require => false
  gem 'database_cleaner', github: 'bmabey/database_cleaner'

  # Uncomment this line on OS X.
  # gem 'growl', '1.0.3'

  # Uncomment these lines on Linux.
  # gem 'libnotify', '0.8.0'

  # Uncomment these lines on Windows.
  # gem 'rb-notifu', '0.0.4'
  # gem 'win32console', '1.3.2'
end

gem 'sass-rails', '4.0.0'
gem 'uglifier', '2.1.1'
gem 'coffee-rails', '4.0.0'
gem 'jquery-rails', '2.2.1'
gem 'turbolinks', '1.1.1'
gem 'jbuilder', '1.0.2'

group :doc do
  gem 'sdoc', '0.3.20', require: false
end

group :production do
  gem 'pg', '0.15.1'
  gem 'rails_12factor', '0.0.2'
end
```

Am I missing any other information? What is the appropriate step to fix this error?

EDIT:

Spec helper here:

```
require 'spec_helper'
# Specs in this file have access to a helper object that includes
# the StaticPagesHelper. For example:
# describe StaticPagesHelper do
#   describe "string concat" do
#     it "concats two strings with spaces" do
#       helper.concat_strings("this","that").should == "this that"
#     end
#   end
# end
#describe StaticPagesHelper do
#   pending "add some examples to (or delete) #{__FILE__}"
#end
```

I notice that it is empty, however, the tutorial's steps did not require any changes.

Comment: try running rspec without '\', i.e. simply type 
$ bundle exec rspec spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb > -e "signup with invalid information"

Comment: You said you were sharing your `spec_helper` file, but that's not what you shared. Would you please share your `spec_helper` file?

Comment: @SachinSingh - I tried running rspec per your suggestion, but the same error message shows.

Comment: @PeterAlfvin I've added the spec helper, but it is empty. Do you think this is the source of the error?

Comment: What are you trying to do with `\ >` in your rspec command line?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your error says the framework cannot load the file `"/Users/kelvinyu/rails_projects/sample_app/signup with invalid information"` which clearly isn't a file—the file is `"spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb"`. Try having everything in one line—without the `\ >` (this *slash angle bracket* only means that there, maybe, was a line break when Michael Hartl was typing up the tutorial.

Also, look to using [describe and *context*](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-core/docs/example-groups/basic-structure-describe-it) interchangeably. This would make you write clearer specs. There is no magic to it. The sourcecode for RSpec shows that `context` is just another name for `describe`. But when you write specs with both, the meanings are clearer.

Comment: Thank you for explaining. This solution worked it seems that the `\ >` was a line break. The correct command should have been `bundle exec rspec spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb \ `

Comment: I think you're still misunderstanding the situation. The "-e" specifies what test to run. If you omit the argument altogether, you're running the entire file.

Comment: Also, would you mind pointing to whatever you were looking at in the tutorial that included the `\ >`?

Comment: @PeterAlfvin Sure! Right after Figure 7.17 at [link](http://ruby.railstutorial.org/chapters/sign-up#sec-signup_error_messages). So after I run rspec as stated above as `bundle exec rspec spec/requests/user_pages_spec.rb \ `, the `>` shows and I am able to run the rest of the test by typing in `-e "signup with invalid information"`

Comment: @PeterAlfvin That is where I saw the `\ >` in use, but I actually misread that section as one command line.

Comment: Thanks for the follow-up. I was mistakenly looking after Listing 7.17 rather than Figure 7.17. Anyway, after searching through the tutorial I found the place with the `\ >`, while most places in the tutorial had it all on one line or broken across two with just the `\` and not the `>`. Thanks again.